# Why can't I send data twice on socket connection?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I am writing a simple client server socket program and cannot figure out why my client only sends the first time the send button is pressed.

The second time "nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);" is called, the server does not get the data...

NOTE: I have commented out the echoing from the server to client, as the server was closing the connection after the echo.  I want the connection to remain open.

Please help me send data twice ...

Here is the C# FORM client code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    TcpClient client;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox_IP.Text = "192.168.0.72";
    }

    const int PORT_NO = 11000;
    private void button_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client = new TcpClient(textBox_IP.Text, PORT_NO);
        textBox_MsgToSend.Text = "Started";
    }

    private void button_Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string textToSend = textBox_MsgToSend.Text + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        textToSend += "<EOF>";

        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);

        //---send the text---
        textBox_Sending.Text = textToSend;
        textBox_Size.Text = bytesToSend.Length.ToString();
        nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

       // commented out as the server does not echo anything back
       //---read back the text---
       //            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
       //            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
       //            textBox_Received.Text = bytesRead.ToString();
    }

    private void button_Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client.Close();
        textBox_MsgToSend.Text = "Closed";
    }

}
```

Here is the form designer code:

```
partial class Form1
{
    // <summary>
    // Required designer variable.
    // </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    // <summary>
    // Clean up any resources being used.
    // </summary>
    // <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button_Start = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button_Send = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button_Close = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.textBox_MsgToSend = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox_Received = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox_IP = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox_Sending = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox_Size = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button_Start
        // 
        this.button_Start.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 28);
        this.button_Start.Name = "button_Start";
        this.button_Start.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button_Start.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button_Start.Text = "Start";
        this.button_Start.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button_Start.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Start_Click);
        // 
        // button_Send
        // 
        this.button_Send.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 73);
        this.button_Send.Name = "button_Send";
        this.button_Send.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button_Send.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button_Send.Text = "Send";
        this.button_Send.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button_Send.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Send_Click);
        // 
        // button_Close
        // 
        this.button_Close.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 172);
        this.button_Close.Name = "button_Close";
        this.button_Close.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button_Close.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button_Close.Text = "Close";
        this.button_Close.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button_Close.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Close_Click);
        // 
        // textBox_MsgToSend
        // 
        this.textBox_MsgToSend.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 73);
        this.textBox_MsgToSend.Name = "textBox_MsgToSend";
        this.textBox_MsgToSend.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(207, 20);
        this.textBox_MsgToSend.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // textBox_Received
        // 
        this.textBox_Received.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 174);
        this.textBox_Received.Name = "textBox_Received";
        this.textBox_Received.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(207, 20);
        this.textBox_Received.TabIndex = 4;
        // 
        // textBox_IP
        // 
        this.textBox_IP.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 28);
        this.textBox_IP.Name = "textBox_IP";
        this.textBox_IP.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 20);
        this.textBox_IP.TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(117, 57);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 7;
        this.label1.Text = "Message to Send";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(117, 96);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 9;
        this.label2.Text = "Sending:";
        // 
        // textBox_Sending
        // 
        this.textBox_Sending.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 112);
        this.textBox_Sending.Name = "textBox_Sending";
        this.textBox_Sending.ReadOnly = true;
        this.textBox_Sending.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(207, 20);
        this.textBox_Sending.TabIndex = 8;
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this.label3.AutoSize = true;
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(330, 96);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 13);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 11;
        this.label3.Text = "Size";
        // 
        // textBox_Size
        // 
        this.textBox_Size.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(333, 112);
        this.textBox_Size.Name = "textBox_Size";
        this.textBox_Size.ReadOnly = true;
        this.textBox_Size.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(65, 20);
        this.textBox_Size.TabIndex = 10;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(447, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox_Size);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox_Sending);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox_IP);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox_Received);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox_MsgToSend);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button_Close);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button_Send);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button_Start);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Client";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button_Start;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button_Send;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button_Close;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox_MsgToSend;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox_Received;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox_IP;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox_Sending;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox_Size;
}
```

Now the server

The server is a console application that has two classes and a main

```
// State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Here is the server code:

```
public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    // Thread signal.
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public AsynchronousSocketListener()
    {
    }

    public static void StartListening(string ip)
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ip);

        Console.WriteLine("listening on IP " + ip + " Port " + "11000");

        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(address, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        Console.WriteLine("Connected...");

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ReadCallback");

        string content = string.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
            // more data.
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the 
                // client. Display it on the console.
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}", content.Length, content);

                // I commented this out as when the send completes, the server closes the connection... I want the connection to remain open
                // Echo the data back to the client.
                //Send(handler, content);
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        Console.WriteLine("Echo back to client : " + data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

here is main:

```
public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartListening( "192.168.0.72" );
    return 0;
}
```

Attempt 1:

I tried this in the public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) function:

```
    while(true)
    {
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }
```

Attempt2:

Per SpaceghostAli's reply/code : doesn't work... crashes on second send

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    string content = string.Empty;

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ReadCallback");

        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
        // more data.
        content = state.sb.ToString();
        if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
        {
            // All the data has been read from the 
            // client. Display it on the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. Data : {1}", content.Length, content);

            state = new StateObject();
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

            // Echo the data back to the client.
            //                Send(handler, content);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not all data received. Get more.
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
    }
}
```

Attempt 3:

Another try based on what David said, but resetting the BeginReceive at end of function - WORKS !

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    string content = string.Empty;

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ReadCallback");

        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
        // more data.
        content = state.sb.ToString();
        if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
        {
            // All the data has been read from the 
            // client. Display it on the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. Data : {1}", content.Length, content);

            // Echo the data back to the client.
            Send(handler, content);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not all data received. Get more.
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
    }

    // clear the state object's buffer and queue the next begin receive
    state.sb.Clear();
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}
```

Comment: That line you've added under Attempt 1 should be in the if(content.IndexOf("<EOF>" > -1) block. After you've successfully read the data you need to tell the socket to read again.

Comment: Also when reading again you may need to clear your buffer or adjust the write position depending on if you want to append to it or throw away what you've read before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've upvoted David's answer as I believe it is correct so please mark it as such, this is just to clarify what he meant based on your update

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ReadCallback");

    string content = string.Empty;

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
        // more data.
        content = state.sb.ToString();
        if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
        {
            // All the data has been read from the 
            // client. Display it on the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}", content.Length, content);

            // continue reading
            state = new StateObject();
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

            // I commented this out as when the send completes, the server closes the connection... I want the connection to remain open
            // Echo the data back to the client.
            //Send(handler, content);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not all data received. Get more
            // start writing at bytesRead in the buffer so you don't lose the partially read data
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, bytesRead, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once your server reads the message and then writes it to the console, it never starts reading again.  It just exits "ReadCallback".  The server's connection stays open, but it will never read any more.

To fix this, you should probably start another "BeginReceive" after you write out the last received message.

Comment: I tried this:          while(true)
        {
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        } -- that didn't work.. there has to be a way to keep the server responding to a client connection